# Which type of table storage will give high performance?

Tags: mysql, performance

A table with 3 columns, 1000000 records. Another table with 20 columns, 5000000 records. From the above which table gives quick output while query for data. Provided both table has auto increment value as primary key?

To represent more clearly,
 Lets say, table1 has 3 columns with 1million records,1 field is indexed. And also table2 has 30 columns with 10lakh records, 5 field is indexed. If I run query to select a data from table1 and the next query to fetch data from table2 ( columns are indexed on both tables ), which table gives output much quicker than others?

Comment: Those are actually very low numbers of rows by most SQL standards. Table storage will have very minimal impact, it will be more about how you have set up your keys and indexes

Comment: @mattedgod thanks for your comments. But lets say, table1 has 3 columns with 1million records,1 field is indexed. And also table2 has 30 columns with 10lakh records, 5 field is indexed. From this which one has higher performance. I just want to know how mysql search query patterns works. is it based on column fields or number of records...

Comment: ah that's a different question entirely. But again, those column numbers are low so the row count is going to impact your performance much more than the number of columns

Comment: Isn't 10 [lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) the same as 1 million?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sizes you mentioned, the tables are so small that it won't matter.

Generally speaking though `MyISAM` will be a bit faster than `InnoDB` for pretty much any table although it seems like the gap there is closing all the time.

Keep in mind though that for a small performance penalty, InnoDB gives you a lot in terms of ACID compliance.